# Getting amount of pending POST/GET requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

with my current project I have to check if there are any pending POST or GET requests. If there still are pending requests the user can't navigate to another page, but somehow I just can't figure out how to get the amount of pending requests as shown below.

[image]

I already tried `.ajaxComplete()` and `document.readyState` but these aren't the things I am looking for. And on the internet I can't find a solution or function for this particular thing.

Can someone please tell me where to look for?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not increment a global counter each time you make a request? Then just decrement the counter in the done() function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the image you made where from a dev-tool of a browser. This information isn't normally available via JS. Like @john said, the simple way is to increment a global counter when starting a AJAX request and decrement it when finished.

I would prefer a array containing the AJAX-Objects and look at the length of the array. When ever a request is finished (`finally`-function) remove this request from array. You could implement a button "kill" all pending requests. In advanced you can also put the starting time into the array and show the consumed time (like your screen shot).

I could provide code but i think it isn't a big thing, more time consuming is to add this counter/array to every AJAX-Call.

Comment: I'll try this, if works ill accept the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery provides global ajax event handler (explicit: [`.ajaxSend()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/) and [`.ajaxComplete()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/)) with which you are able to build an easy global counter, like John suggested.

With this approach you do not have to attach a handler to each request you make, if there are multiple occurrences in your code.

```
var ajaxCounter = 0;
$(function() {
    $(document).ajaxSend(function() {
        ajaxCounter++;
        console.log("New Request! There are " + ajaxCounter + " requests running.");
    }).ajaxComplete(function() {
        ajaxCounter--;
        console.log("Request finished! There are " + ajaxCounter + " requests running.");
    });
});
```